# Django app example from django creators

Tags: django, coding-style

I have in mind some projects in django and I'd like to follow some "best practices" of django, but it seems to be that its something that isn't already standarized.

So, I thought that maybe i can learn from apps written by django creators.

What apps in django were written by some of the django creators?
Where can I find them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a bit on github.com actually.
https://github.com/search?q=django&type=Everything

Also if you google "django applications" you get quite a bit.
http://djangopackages.com/
http://www.django-apps.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was looking for some app written by django creators. djangopackages.com is a good site to find django apps by the way

Comment: Oh ok, you mean these guys? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/internals/committers  
This http://pinaxproject.com was started by some of the developers of Django.

Comment: James Tauber was/is a dev for the Django project and here's a list of the code he's working on. http://jtauber.com/open_source_software/

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it at first!